# Azure Scaleset - is there a Get-AzureRmVmssDiagnosticsExtension

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there a Get-AzureRmVmssDiagnosticsExtension. How do I get if a scale set has diagnostics enabled and what storage it is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no command to get the storage account directly.
But we can use PowerShell to the information of vmss, like this:

```
PS C:\Users> get-azurermvmss -ResourceGroupName  vmss -VMScaleSetName vmss
```

[image]